# HTML Email - Image Display issue - Image floats below joining cell

Tags: html, email, mobile-safari, twig, html-email

I have an HTML email that has a display issue with an image when the joining cell doesn't have the full Phone number w/ Extension

Twig Values

```
office_phone = 800-555-1212
office_extension = 123 ( optional )
```

HTML

```
<table align="center" style="margin:0 auto;background:#fff;" border="0" width="660" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>

            <!-- there is more code here but this is the section having the display issue -->

            <table style="background:#191b1d;padding-left:40px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="660">
                <tr>
                    <td width="40%" style="color:#fff;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;">
                        Call {{ office_phone }}{% if office_extension %} x{{ office_extension }}{% endif %}
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%" style="margin:0 auto;padding-left:40px;">
                        <img style="display:block;border:none;" src="the_image.png" alt="Hello Image">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- end display issue -->

        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

When office_extension is displayed, things look great

[image]

When office_extension is NOT displayed we have the issue

[image]

What could be causing the display issue?

NOTE: The display issue only happens on iPad / iOS 7 / Mobile Safari / Gmail

Comment: The table cells should not fold below like that. Can you replace your dynamic tags with a static number like "Call 800-555-1212 x123" and test again? I'm thinking the extension may contain some hidden markup

Comment: @JustinK the extension is dynamic, so sometimes it's there and other times it's not. I need it to be flexible for both of these options

Comment: The reason I'm saying to replace the dynamic tags with hard coded numbers and test to see if its the dynamic tags that are causing it. If its still causing problems we can eliminate the tags as the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much trial and error it looks like it's Gmail that's the issue.

Here was my problem.

When testing I would send two tests, one with the Phone Extension and one without. Gmail groups these messages and uses the same layout for each message from the first delivered message. So if I sent the email with a Phone extension first the email without the phone extension would have the display issue. If I sent the email without the Phone Extension first, the email with the Phone Extension would have the display issue.

Pro-Tip: Empty Trash and send one email at a time

Comment: Gmail hides repeated/duplicate content in converstions. It is their way of collapsing the thread in long emails. It sounds like this is what is happening here...

Comment: not sure, easiest was to send one at a time and delete, then empty trash

Comment: another pro-tip: send without a subject! then gmail will treat it as a completely new thread.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding on your `<table>` element. Never add padding on tables, always put them in `<td>` only. if you need the whole thing padded, nest it inside another table and pad that table's `<td>`.

Also, set the width on your image to `width="100%"`. That should prevent it from popping out of the desired layout.

It is also possible your dynamic tag is putting something wacky in there. If you use the [Litmus Scope](https://litmus.com/scope/) browser plugin to review the final code that actually arrives in Gmail. This should reveal what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your input +1 for the effort, see my answer as to what was happening